# strings get concatenated on other end in TLS socket connection in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl, buffer

I am tailing a file using [tail-always](https://www.npmjs.com/package/always-tail) 
and transferring data to another server using TLS socket in node. Here is code which transfer lines to another server

```
var client = tls.connect(port,serveraddress, options, function() {
    tail.on('line', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString('utf-8'))
            client.write(data.toString('utf-8'));
    });
    tail.on('error', function(data) {
        console.log("error:", data);
    });
    tail.watch();
});
```

on another side server listens to a port and grabs the text. the code is :

```
var server = tls.createServer(options, function(tslsender) {
    tslsender.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
    });
    tslsender.on('close', function() {
            console.log('closed connection');
    });
});
```

The program works perfectly when a single line is added at a time to the file , but when multiple line is added to the file the lines gets concatenated on server side.I have confirmed that they are not getting concatenated before **client.write** function.
how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `stream` is just a bunch of bytes. Writing one line at a time at one end of a stream has no effect on how that data will be received at the other end. If you want your server to process the data it is receiving one line at a time, you need to do that on the server using something like [`split`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split).

```
var split = require('split');

var server = tls.createServer(options, function(tslsender) {
    let lineStream = tslsender.pipe(split());
    lineStream.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
    });

    tslsender.on('close', function() {
        console.log('closed connection');
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply split did not work so in my case I have to use regex inside split for line seperation